# Is there a way to get thread stack address?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm investigating some memory leak and looked at the `/proc/<pid>/maps` and at the currently running threads:

```
# ps -T -p 11528
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
11528 11528 ?        00:00:00 bin
11528 11529 ?        00:00:01 bin
11528 11532 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11533 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11534 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11535 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11536 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11537 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11538 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11539 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11540 ?        00:00:02 bin
11528 11541 ?        00:00:02 bin
```

Is there a way to know where does the address of some thread's stack start? E.g. my process pid is 11528. How to get the address of the tid 11529 so I can dump the stack with `gdb`?

Comment: You can switch the thread with `thread 11529` in gdb and then print your esp/rsp. See also http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html

Comment: You can attach `gdb` to `spid` `gdb -p <spid>` then use `info frame` or `print $esp/$rsp` should help.

Comment: @Ctx I just printed the rsp of the thread `11529`,  `print $rsp $1 = (void *) 0x7f7dad0f1bc0` and since `11529` is a child of `11528` I did `grep 7f7dad0f1bc0 /proc/11528/maps` and found nothing. The map it contains was like the following `7f7dacff6000-7f7dad0f5000`. Why? I expected that the top of the stack can be found there.

Comment: @SomeName: The thread's `%rsp` has been decremented from the top of stack because it has used part of the stack - you can tell that's the right stack because `%rsp` lies between the start and end addresses of the mapping.